# configure MySQL8.0 on centos7

Tags: mysql, centos7

First, when excuting an order
`mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`, it would go wrong.

Second,when excuting an order

```
systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 三 2019-10-30 01:29:29 CST; 20min ago
  Process: 30824 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock User=mysql (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 30824 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

10月 30 01:29:29 VM_0_6_centos systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
10月 30 01:29:29 VM_0_6_centos systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
10月 30 01:29:29 VM_0_6_centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
10月 30 01:29:29 VM_0_6_centos systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
10月 30 01:29:29 VM_0_6_centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Third, default_file of mysql is my.cnf:

```
  1 # For advice on how to change settings please see
  2 # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
  3
  4 [mysqld]
  5 #
  6 # Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
  7 # cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
  8 # innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
  9 #
 10 # Remove the leading "# " to disable binary logging
 11 # Binary logging captures changes between backups and is enabled by
 12 # default. It's default setting is log_bin=binlog
 13 # disable_log_bin
 14 #
 15 # Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
 16 # The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
 17 # Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
 18 # join_buffer_size = 128M
 19 # sort_buffer_size = 2M
 20 # read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
 21 #
 22 # Remove leading # to revert to previous value for default_authentication_plugin,
 23 # this will increase compatibility with older clients. For background, see:
 24 # https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentic    ation_plugin
 25 # default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
 26
 27 datadir=/var/lib/mysql
 28 socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
 29
 30 log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
 31 pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 32
 33 [mysql]
 34
 35 socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
 36 [client]
 37 socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Fourth,I can't find mysql.sock, mysql.server and mysql_safe in my machine.After install mysql-server, it still go wrong.

```
yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@VM_0_6_centos /root]# find ./* -name mysql.server
```

What can I do?

Comment: What do you get if you try to run this from your shell as root? `/usr/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` ?

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `systemctl is-enabled mysqld`?

Comment: Put bind-address  = localhost into your my.cnf file

Comment: all the order are runned as root, and mysqld is enabled.Besides, putting bind-address = localhost into my.cnf file doesn't work.

Comment: @zero what's show in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/mysqld.log` it should give more details.